# Getting XML nodevalue with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, nodevalue

I am trying to figure out how to get a node's value in Javascript. I've read a few tutorials but the examples they use are all much more complex than what I'm doing..

Here's my Javascript

```
        if(xmlhttpp.readyState==4 && xmlhttpp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("ajax_status").innerHTML=xmlhttpp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('status').nodeValue;
        }
```

And the XML is..

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<resp><fname>Kyla</fname>
<lname>Bonds</lname>
<addr>6916 S Elizabeth Street</addr>
<city>Chicago</city>
<street>IL</street>
<zip>60636</zip>
<phone></phone>
<email>Kbonds20@gmail.com</email>
<status>Found user</status></resp>
```

How can I get "Found User" from this?

Comment: Just a tiny point and not an answer to your question but the object would usually be referred to as xmlhttp rather than xmlhttpp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
xmlhttpp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('status')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```