# Parse XML through JavaScript and get node value

Tags: javascript

My code is like this

```
   var tariffdate = PriceSheet.children('TariffEffDate')[1].text;
```

Where I expect to get data inside `TariffEffDate` tag. But it gives me `undefined` instead.

I can Get `<TariffEffDate>1999-01-01T00:00:00</TariffEffDate>` as a result for code

```
  console.log(PriceSheet.children('TariffEffDate')[1])
```

But when I add `.text` to get data inside this node it is giving me `undefined`.
Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to use `.nodeValue` instead of `.text` IIRC.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I have tried and result is Null

Comment: [Someone else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249605/getting-xml-nodevalue-with-javascript) had to use `[1].firstChild.nodeValue` instead of `[1].nodeValue`. Perhaps that would fix it?

Comment: @h2ooooooo That solved the issue, You can add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) instead of `.text`.

`.children('TariffEffDate')[1]` will give you a [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) that inherits [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), but it won't give you a leaf node, meaning that this HTMLElement might have multiple children. This is why you cannot get the value of (technically) multiple child-nodes. You can access the first node by calling [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild).

Essentially, you want your final code to be:

```
var tariffdate = PriceSheet.children('TariffEffDate')[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
```